# AWS HTTP API Gateway with dozens of routes, how should Lambda integration(s) be structured?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-http-api

I tried creating a single Lambda function using the Node.js language, to handle a few routes of the API. Already the function seems too complex. Is it more common to have individual Lambda functions as integration for each route ?
Does anyone have examples of such functions ?
Are there other options for handling a large HTTP API ?

Comment: Isn't this a api design question?

Comment: The API doesn't change if the integration function changes. Or if the integration function has multiple instead of one. Does that answer ok? But if it is an api design question, do I need to ask in a different forum then? Which one?